# WM_NCHITTEST not working in WS_EX_LAYERED form

Tags: delphi

I'm using the code of this article http://melander.dk/articles/alphasplash/ to display a 32 bit bitmap in a form, but when i try to use a solid color bitmap instead of a image the  WM_NCHITTEST message is not  received and i cann't move the form. If I use 32 bitmap image the code work just fine. What i'm missing here?

This is the code

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  protected
    { Private declarations }
    procedure WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest); message WM_NCHITTEST;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1 : TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  BlendFunction: TBlendFunction;
  BitmapPos: TPoint;
  BitmapSize: TSize;
  exStyle: DWORD;
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
begin
  // Enable window layering
  exStyle := GetWindowLongA(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
  if (exStyle and WS_EX_LAYERED = 0) then
    SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, exStyle or WS_EX_LAYERED);

  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
   //Bitmap.LoadFromFile('splash.bmp'); //if I use a image the code works fine

    Bitmap.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
    Bitmap.SetSize(Width, Height);    
    Bitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color:=clRed;
    Bitmap.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0,0, Bitmap.Width, Bitmap.Height));

    // Position bitmap on form
    BitmapPos := Point(0, 0);
    BitmapSize.cx := Bitmap.Width;
    BitmapSize.cy := Bitmap.Height;


    // Setup alpha blending parameters
    BlendFunction.BlendOp := AC_SRC_OVER;
    BlendFunction.BlendFlags := 0;
    BlendFunction.SourceConstantAlpha := 255;
    BlendFunction.AlphaFormat := AC_SRC_ALPHA;

    UpdateLayeredWindow(Handle, 0, nil, @BitmapSize, Bitmap.Canvas.Handle,
      @BitmapPos, 0, @BlendFunction, ULW_ALPHA);
    Show;
  finally
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest);
begin
  Message.Result := HTCAPTION;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with:

```
BlendFunction.SourceConstantAlpha := 150; // 255 is fully opaque.
BlendFunction.AlphaFormat := 0;
```

Because your bitmap data has no source alpha. `AlphaFormat` for a TBitmap is by default `afIgnored`. 'AC_SRC_ALPHA' is only used with images having color values premultiplied with alpha. The images you are loading from the disk probably has proper alpha channel.

I can't really guess what's the relation with 'WM_NC_HITTEST' but wrong inputs yields wrong results :).

Comment: +1, don't get what it means, but I'm sure you know :-) I was just taking this problem by my intuition.

Comment: @TLama - Don't be so sure! <g> I voted for your answer because I thought the same for you. Really, I'm not an expert, but it is clearly documented in 'BLENDFUNCTION'. My view is that, your answer was also correct. The only problem with it was that it produced an image with arbitrary alpha values, but in a one-color bitmap that's no problem..